# Using custom subclass of NSURLConnection, how does it "find" the additional data in the class later?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, inheritance

This blog offers a nice solution for handling multiple NSURLConnections: make a custom "CustomURLConnection" class that has an additional `tag` property.

http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/02/custom-nsurlconnection-class-with-tag/

http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/15/multiple-async-nsurlconnections-example/

Basically, he has simply added a `tag` property to the exsisting NSURLConnection:

**CustomURLConnection.m**

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately tag:(NSString*)tag {
   self = [super initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:startImmediately];

   if (self) {
      self.tag = tag;
   }
   return self;
}
```

then, later in the normal NSURLConnection loading methods, you can do:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

   //Log the connection’s tag
   CustomURLConnection *ttttag = (CustomURLConnection *)connection; // **HERE**
   NSLog(@”%@”, ttttag.tag);


   NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(CustomURLConnection*)connection];
   [connection release];
}
```

So, that's where I'm having trouble. The way I see it, this is how things go:

- I create a "connection+tag"
- The first code snippet I posted above creates a regular "connection" (no `tag`), which will eventually call the the normal NSURLConnection methods like `connectionDidFinishLoading`. What happens to the `tag` at this point?
- In the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method I'm able to cast the connection back into a "connection+tag", then find that missing tag information that had been discarded. How?

Maybe I'm just confusing myself, but it seems as if the `tag` was discarded when it starts down the normal `NSURLConnection` path. But then by casting it as the subclass, I'm again able to recover the `tag` property. Where did it live/go in the mean time?

Could someone with a better understanding of inheritance explain this to me?

Comment: You are not doing an actual typecast, all Obj-C objects are simply a pointer to a memory address. You're only telling the compiler to *assume* it's a `CustomURLConnection` at compile time and this has no impact at all on the actual execution of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code:

```
[[CustomURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:... delegate:... startImmediately:... startImmediately tag:...];
```

you create an instance of `CustomURLConnection`. Now here is where your understanding is wrong: this `CustomURLConnection` object can freely call all methods of its superclasses but it will always remain a `CustomURLConnection`. The `tag` is always there.

The methods that are defined in the superclass such as `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` don't know about the tag but they don't have to, either. When the delegate method gets called:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

the `connection` argument is the *very same* `CustomURLConnection` that you created yourself above. The type in the method signature is different but that doesn't matter; because you know that this connection is of the `CustomURLConnection` type, you can just cast the `connection` object to the correct type and access the new property. But even if you wouldn't do that, the `tag` would still be there all the time.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good explanation. Especially *"the methods don't know about the tag but they don't have to, either."*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> The first code snippet I posted above creates a regular "connection" (no tag).

What you've done here is create a subclass of `NSURLConnection`. Anywhere you can use the latter, you can use the former. `NSURLConnection*` means "a pointer to an `NSURLConnection*` or a subclass of it." So the original object you created was a `CustomURLConnection` and it included an extra ivar. That ivar doesn't disappear just because intermediary users refer to it by its superclass.