# creating notification from connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to send HTTP request, I am using NSURLConnection like this:

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                               initWithRequest:request
                               delegate:self
                               startImmediately:YES];
```

At the end of connectionDidFinishLoading, I need to post different notifications, depending on the HTTP request that was just completed.
However inside connectionDidFinishLoading I don't have a clear logical identifier to the type of the request that was send:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

// here i want to post various notifications, depending on the HTTP request that was completed 


}
```

What is the best solution here? Thanks!

Comment: You can subclass NSURLConnection to store additional properties that are needed in the callback. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331303/using-custom-subclass-of-nsurlconnection-how-does-it-find-the-additional-data for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Connection did finish method passes the NSURLConnection object, which has the request and url:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"currentRequest: %@", connection.currentRequest);
    NSLog(@"originalRequest: %@", connection.originalRequest);

    // here do a if statement that compares url
    if ([connection.currentRequest.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"http://google.co.uk"]) {
        NSLog(@"Equal to google");
        // post notification 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out :-) But the URL by itself is not always informative enough to correlate with a specific request.. Any chance there is a more explicit info I can pass to this method and use it to identify the request?

Comment: i can only think of http header fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use framework like [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit). In this framework you can write like this:

```
- (void) sendRequest: (NSString*) aRequestPath
          httpMethod: (NSString*) aHttpMethod
         paramsBlock: (SMFillParametersForRequestBlock) aParamsBlock
        successBlock: (SMSaveRequestResultBlock) aSuccessBlock
          errorBlock: (SMErrorRequestResultBlock) aErrorBlock
            userInfo: (id) anUserInfo
{

    MKNetworkEngine* network_engine= [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName: MuseumsHostName];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (aParamsBlock)
    {
        aParamsBlock(params);
    }

    MKNetworkOperation* operation = [network_engine operationWithPath: aRequestPath
                                                               params: params
                                                           httpMethod: aHttpMethod
                                                                  ssl: NO];
    [operation onCompletion: ^(MKNetworkOperation* completedOperation){

        // parse response of current request:
        aSuccessBlock(completedOperation, anUserInfo, ...); 

    } onError: ^(NSError *error){

       // error handler: call block

    }];

    [network_engine enqueueOperation: operation];
}
```

Believe me, this is the best solution